# Back button fails after window.location.replace(href);

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, opera

I made simple function which makes all container behave like link ("a" element).

```
function allHot(element){
$(element)
.click(
    function(){
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    window.location.replace(href);
})

.hover(
    function(){
    $(this).css({'text-shadow' : '0px 1px 0px #D6D6D6'});
    },
    function(){
    $(this).css({'text-shadow' : 'none'});
    }

);
}
```

Function works great. Instead of clicking the "more" button, user can click everywhere on container and is properly redirected.

However, if user after redirection clicks back button, browser goes back two steps instead of one as it should. What's more weird, history looks OK.

Simple scheme to better description:

> Page1 -> Page2
>
> Page2 [user clicks on "allHot" container] -> allHot redirects to Page3
>
> Page3 [user clicks on browser back button] -> Page1

This is major bug for website I'm working on right now. I don't really have a clue to prevent it. Bug tested on Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

Tested also on Opera "no javascript mode". If javascript is disabled issue doesn't occure.

Thanks in advance for any clue or solution.

Answer (score 46):

Instead of using `replace`, use the following:

```
window.location.href = ''
```

Comment: Note: If you're like me and find that the back button still doesn't work after redirecting as mentioned above, make sure you're using the full url e.g. `http://www.example.com/endpoint`.  Using just `/endpoint` was still failing.

Comment: window.location.assign(url); worked for me as Chrome was having problems with .href

Comment: Thank you for this. This did the trick for my issue.

Comment: window.location.assign(url); is the correct answer!!! Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Adding to MarcoK's answer.

When using `replace` you are replacing the history state so you are not pushing one more state to the history.

If you have the following:

`Page1` to `State1`

`Page2` to `State2`

and then you use replace you will be replacing `Page3` to `State2`.

When you press the back button you will go from `State2` to `State1` and that is why you are going to `Page1`.

When using `window.location.href` you are adding one more state so `Page3` will be set to `State3` and when you click the back button you will go to `State2` wich has `Page2` as URL.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.