# Javascript redirect, fastest way to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, meta

I'm using javascript and `localStorage` to redirect.

But I have found that there are a lot of ways to do that. Here are a few:

```
document.location
document.location.href
window.open(url,how)
window.location
top.location
window.navigate() //not sure that this works
```

and the html meta way

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.google.com"/>
```

I am just interested which of the above (or any other code) will redirect faster. As for info I will use it to redirect (to a website) google chrome when new tab is opened.

Comment: have you tried to see what method meets your needs?

Comment: all of those above meet the needs, but I can't see which way is faster?

Comment: why is speed important? all of these should be reasonably "fast". there are many factors outside of these calls that would cause a problem.

Comment: as I mentioned I will use it for new tab redirect. Here even a millisecond matters

Comment: Speed in terms of what? Data transfer time will be governed by client connection/server spec. The only measurable speed is down to the browsers' internal javascript implementation, in which case the difference between one call to each of those will be in the nano seconds - except `meta`, that will be slow so avoid that.

Comment: because I am using chrome extension it can't write inline javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meta redirect is an awful hack and it breaks the back button. Never use it.

The rest is basically equivalent. `window.location` is most common.

The fastest way may be not to redirect from JS, but to use `<a href>` (with a click handler if you need to perform some operation before navigation), which e.g. enables browsers to prefetch DNS.

Comment: Also the "`window.location.replace(href)`" breaks the back-button ([look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844430/back-button-fails-after-window-location-replacehref/))